# Android touch events with multiple views

Tags: java, android, events, touch, multi-touch

How can I have different views accepting different touch events at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onTouchEvent for the views, and then ensure that you return false so that the touches can fall through. Touches will start at the "top" and fall through each View in your layout till they reach the bottom inner-most view.